# sliding the text up and background down on mouseover event

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown

I have a small problem with sliding function. What I want it to do is when I mouseover the button, the darker background will slide down covering the whole button (behind the text) and text will slide up a little bit. What I have done so far is this:

```
<nav>
    <a href="../webdesign.html"><span>01. <strong>HOME</strong></span><div></div></a>
    <a href="../webdesign.html"><span>02. <strong>WEBSITE DESIGN</strong></span><div></div></a>
    <a href="../webdesign.html"><span>03. <strong>MOBILE WEBSITES</strong></span><div></div></a>
    <a href="../webdesign.html"><span>04. <strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></span><div></div></a>
    <a href="../webdesign.html"><span>05. <strong>ABOUT US</strong></span><div></div></a>
    <a href="../webdesign.html"><span>06. <strong>CONTACT US</strong></span><div></div></a>
</nav>
```

jquery:

```
$("nav a").mouseenter(function(){
      $('div', this).slideDown(200);
      $("nav a").css('padding-top', '5px');
}).mouseleave(function() {
      $('div', this).slideUp(500);
      $("nav a").css('padding-top', '25px');
});
```

css:

```
    nav{
        height:65px;
        font-family: moderne, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size:0.9em;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    nav a{
        background-color:rgba(000,000,000,0.1);
        border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
        border-top:1px solid #666;
        display:block;
        float:left;
        padding: 25px 0 0 10px;
        width: 144px;
        height:65px;
        color:#ffd100;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 0 2px;
        border-right: solid 1px #fff;
        border-left: solid 1px #666;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 1px 1px 3px inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 1px 1px 3px inset;
        box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 1px 1px 3px inset;
        position:relative;
    }

    nav a strong{
        font-weight:normal;
        color:#333;
    }

    nav div{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        float:left;
        width:144px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        color:#ddd;
        padding:5px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #999;
        font-size:15px; 
        display:none;
    }
```

I know jquery is a bit of disaster, but I tried many things, I'm a beginner in jquery.
jsFiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bFFhk/1/)
Thank you for your help.

Comment: `$("nav a")..css(` i get the feeling that it isn't query that is the disaster. :)

Comment: i thought about putting this into a proper div, but i heard nav is a common used tag and can replace a div. This is my first use of nav and other html5 tags. I tried to replace it with a 'div' but didn't give any results so i left it as it is.

Comment: @GungFoo Thanks for your help, I appreciate your time, unfortunately I'm just a beginner in this and it doesn't give me much information what to fix. I've got a feeling the whole jquery I've done may be unusable.

Comment: your code is simply riddled with errors. use a javascript console to find them before asking anything (part of the required research). i edited your question and fixed what i could see at first glance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/bFFhk/2/

```
$("nav a").mouseenter(function () {
    $('div', this).slideDown(200);
    $(this).css('padding-top', '5px');
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('div', this).slideUp(500);
    $(this).css('padding-top', '25px');
});
```

This adds a  little animation : http://jsfiddle.net/bFFhk/3/

Comment: thanks that's almost there, how can I make the text to go up fluently, so using something like slide up function? Instead of just jumping? thanks for your help :)

Comment: Welcome... Happy to be Helpful.. :)

Comment: @A.V In your fiddle you should stop animation and remove queued animations before applying new animations. This way if a user hovers over the elements multiple times. All the queued animations will be played.

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik how to do it? can you please show me this on the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/bFFhk/3/  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @A.V Jehanzeb.Malik suggested to stop the animation and remove queued animations before applying new animations. As when you hover the button couple times it will keep repeating the animation. How to stop it from doing that? I'm sure it's something simple but unfortunately not for me and not at this level of my knowledge of jquery.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ppPry/. I have used @A.V's fiddle and build upon it. I have made changes in script and in css of `nav div`